# jQuery onClick has to lead to intermittent display of a <div> or image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visibility

I would like the user of my website to be able to click on an image or div, which will provoke the intermittent display of the element. A sort of stroboscopic-like effect in the following fashion (http://goo.gl/7uk7i5) except that I want this element to be hidden, thus revealing the content that is underneath it.

The inspiration for this effect I took from a past SO thread: http://goo.gl/ks0oJN. So the question here is: can I have actual control over the flickering when hovering over and/or click upon the element? Maybe with some jQuery or Javascripting?

Ideally, the code would allow the user to have some control over the flickering. That is, one click, leads to a certain speed; two clicks, to another speed; third click, back to static display.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide code samples, or link to a fiddle showing the issue?

Comment: Sure. I was having the same issue as the guy I quoted when trying to hide the element when hovering over it. A fiddle of the current status is somewhat changed but this explains what I want to have control over: http://jsfiddle.net/CGFMX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you're wanting to control the flicker effect that your fiddle is demonstrating. The short answer is no.

This effect is caused by the way `:hover` works, which updates every pixel the mouse moves. You've given the hover effect `visibility:hidden` so when you hover on the element it collapses, but now you're no longer hovering over it, so the `:hover` no longer applies. This is reflected on the next pixel which shows the full element again.

The solve for this issue is in this **[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CGFMX/54/)**

*edit* You can't control this via CSS, but look below and see if that works for you.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CGFMX/55/)**

HTML:

```
 <div class="vis-1">
    <div>
        Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body > div {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.vis-1 div {
    height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.vis-1').hover(
    function () {
        (function flicker () {
            $('.vis-1 div').fadeIn(10).delay(50).fadeOut(10);

            flickerTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                flicker();
            }, 100);
        })();
    }, function () {
        clearInterval(flickerTimer);
        $('.vis-1 div').stop(true,true).fadeIn(10);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful indeed. What would it take to display this effect when clicking upon the element? Just a change on the .hover to .onClick? Cheers!

Comment: Yes you could do something similar with `.on('click')` but be mindful to have some way to call `clearInterval(flickerTimer)` otherwise your flickering element will never stop.